# How to add different forms of grades together to get a total grade, in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
Create table course(
stu_no INT,
quiz int,
exam int);
INSERT INTO course (stu_no, quiz, exam) VALUES
(1127, 73, 85);
```

-- So far ive made the table, I still need to create a procedure with a single INOUT parameter that can get the total grade for a given student from this table. Ive forgotten exactly how to create a total

I know I have to do something like SELECT count(*) or something

Answer (score 0):

basically you need something similar to this.

You need to refine it, as i can't extrapolate from only one sample row and without any wanted result you actually want

```
Create table course(
stu_no INT,
quiz int,
exam int);
INSERT INTO course (stu_no, quiz, exam) VALUES
(1127, 73, 85);
```

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_sumgrades(inOUT p_studno_result INT)
BEGIN
    select SUM(exam) INTO  p_studno_result from course WHERE stu_no = p_studno_result;
END
```

```
SET @stu_no = 1127;
call sp_sumgrades(@stu_no);
SELECT @stu_no;
```

| @stu_no |
| --- |
| 85 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rS6WRAU6)